# Custom expiry for replay() operator

Tags: java, rx-java, rx-java3

I have a `Observable<Snapshot>` stream that when subscribed to, replays the event log of every Snapshot produced for every live entity (and any new Snapshot's after the subscription). This replay can contain multiple `Snapshot`s for the same entity. An entity is considered live if its had a snapshot in the last 24 hours.

I am trying to setup a hot observable, that when subscribed to, will replay only the latest `Snapshot` for a given Entity and any new snapshots after the subsription for display in a table in the UI.

Here is the code I have:

```
  Observable<Snapshot> snapshots = getContinuousSnapshotsStream();
  
  var cache = snapshots.groupBy(Snapshot::getId)
    .map(g -> {
        var o = g.timeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
          .onErrorComplete()
          .replay(1);
        o.connect();
        return o.hide();
    })
    .replay(); // memory leak, holds onto references to groups that have timed out already

  // start cache
  cache.connect();
  
  // each client UI subscription will flatten this
  cache.flatMap(o -> o);
```

As you can see from the comment, the reply on the cache will hold onto groups that have already timed out. I need a way to, `onComplete()` of `o`, to remove it from the replay.

Are there any RX operators I can use to achieve my goal without managing a separate cache myself?

Comment: For one, there is a replay overload that eagerly removes old entries to avoid leaks: http://reactivex.io/RxJava/3.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/rxjava3/core/Observable.html#replay-int-boolean-

Comment: @akarnokd - the issue is that the completed observable won't be marked for removal in the first place...

Comment: I don't think this can be done with existing operators. You could get rid of the cached group's item by materializing after `onErrorComplete` so the `replay(1, true)` holds onto a value or the completion indicator. However, removing the entire timed out group from the outer `replay` is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this can't be achieved with standard operators. You'd have to write a custom operator, which can be approximated by using some standard operators and manual internal state management. This is what I came up with:

```java
record MessageValue<T>(T value) { }
record MessageSubscriber<T>(Emitter<T> emitter) { }
record MessageDisposed<T>(Emitter<T> emitter) { }
record MessageTimeout<K>(K key, long id) { }
record CachedValue<T>(T value, long id, Disposable timeout) { }

public static <T, K> Observable<T> groupCacheLatestWithTimeout(
        Observable<T> source, 
        long timeout, TimeUnit unit, Scheduler scheduler,
        Function<T, K> keySelector) {
    Subject<Object> messageQueue = PublishSubject.create().toSerialized(); 
    
    Map<K, CachedValue<T>> cache = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    List<Emitter<T>> emitters = new ArrayList<>();
    
    AtomicLong idGenerator = new AtomicLong();

    var result = Observable.<T>create(emitter -> {
        messageQueue.onNext(new MessageSubscriber<T>(emitter));
        emitter.setCancellable(() -> {
            messageQueue.onNext(new MessageDisposed<T>(emitter));
        });
    });
    
    messageQueue.subscribe(message -> {
        if (message instanceof MessageValue) {
            var mv = ((MessageValue<T>)message).value;
            var key = keySelector.apply(mv);
            
            var old = cache.get(key);
            if (old != null) {
                old.timeout.dispose();
            }
            
            var id = idGenerator.incrementAndGet();
            
            var dispose = scheduler.scheduleDirect(() -> {
                messageQueue.onNext(new MessageTimeout<K>(key, id));
            });
            
            cache.put(key, new CachedValue<T>(mv, id, dispose));
            
            for (var emitter : emitters) {
                emitter.onNext(mv);
            }
        }
        else if (message instanceof MessageSubscriber) {
            
            var me = ((MessageSubscriber<T>)message).emitter;
            emitters.add(me);
            
            for (var entry : cache.values()) {
                me.onNext(entry.value);
            }
        }
        else if (message instanceof MessageDisposed) {
            var md = ((MessageDisposed<T>)message).emitter;
            emitters.remove(md);
        }
        else if (message instanceof MessageTimeout) {
            var mt = ((MessageTimeout<K>)message);
            
            var entry = cache.get(mt.key);
            if (entry.id == mt.id) {
                cache.remove(mt.key);
            }
        }
    });
    
    source.subscribe(value -> {
        messageQueue.onNext(new MessageValue<>(value));
    });

    return result;
}
```

What needs to happen is to create an event loop and serialize interactions with the cache: cache the latest upstream item, timeout the cache entry, manage new subscribers and replays, remove subscribers.

You can test it like this:

```java
var subject = PublishSubject.<String>create();
var sched = new TestScheduler();
var output = groupCacheLatestWithTimeout(subject, 
        5, TimeUnit.SECONDS, sched, 
        k -> k.substring(0, 2));

var to1 = output.test();

to1.assertEmpty();

subject.onNext("g1-1");

to1.assertValuesOnly("g1-1");

subject.onNext("g1-2");

to1.assertValuesOnly("g1-1", "g1-2");

var to2 = output.test();

to2.assertValuesOnly("g1-2");

sched.advanceTimeBy(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

to1.assertValuesOnly("g1-1", "g1-2");
to2.assertValuesOnly("g1-2");

var to3 = output.test();

to3.assertEmpty();

subject.onNext("g1-3");

to1.assertValuesOnly("g1-1", "g1-2", "g1-3");
to2.assertValuesOnly("g1-2", "g1-3");
to3.assertValuesOnly("g1-3");

to1.dispose();

subject.onNext("g1-4");

to1.assertValuesOnly("g1-1", "g1-2", "g1-3");
to2.assertValuesOnly("g1-2", "g1-3", "g1-4");
to3.assertValuesOnly("g1-3", "g1-4");
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I went with. Whilst I think its subjectively simpler than what @akarnkd replied with - I would not have been able to come up with it without having read that answer first.

```
Observable<Snapshot> snapshots = getContinuousSnapshotsStream();

var scheduler = Schedulers.single(); // synchronizer to ensure no race condition where we miss events.
var cache = new LinkedHashMap<String, Observable<Snapshot>>();
var events = snapshots.groupBy(Snapshot::getId)
    .observeOn(scheduler)
    .map(g -> {
        var o = g.timeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS)
          .doFinally(() -> scheduler.scheduleDirect(() -> cache.remove(g.getKey())))
          .replay(1);
        cache.put(g.getKey(), o);
        return o.autoConnect(-1);
    })
    .publish()
    .autoConnect(-1);

// each client UI subscription would subscribe to this:
var sub = Observable.merge(events, Observable.fromIterable(cache.values()))
    .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    .flatmap(r -> r);
```